# Google Chrome selected text

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, google-chrome

I am trying to get selected text from browsers(ie,opera, firefox..) using my C# application.
I tried SendKeys.Send("^c") then reading the selected value from clipboard this method works fine with ie and Firefox.., but it doesn't work with Google Chrome.

How can I get the selected text from Google Chrome and why SendKeys.Send("^c") doesn’t work?

Comment: Chrome handles tabs in seperate processes, that might be your problem.

Comment: gf is right, remember there is at least 2 chrome processes running. you would have to figure out which chrome.exe process refers to the window your trying to execute commands with. try running chrome with --single-process to see if it works (not recommended to stay on)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your replies,

I don’t think tabs in separate processes is my problem because I have the handle to the page where I want to copy selection and I tried PostMessage method with no luck.


Below is the method used.


private const uint VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
private const uint VK_C = 0x43;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool PostMessage(int hwnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

PostMessage(googleChromePageHandle, VK_CONTROL, (int)VK_C, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this will help, but this guy has a Chrome extension that does that I believe, plus its opensource to check it out. Sorry if it was of no help.
[Auto Copy](http://www.stratusnine.com/trac/Auto-Copy/)